# How to load data and reuse with promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a rest backend service which i am using to loading some data, In angular side i want to use it show tabs in UI so in main controller i am using like this:

```
$scope.checkTabAvailable = function () {

    getEPJFeatures().then(function (features) {
        $log.info("available features length in checkpoint.." + features.length);

    });

    return true;
}

var listFeatures=[];
function getEPJFeatures() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    if (listFeatures) {
        d.resolve(listFeatures);
    }
    else {
        $http.get(urlService.restClientUrl("available_features"))
            .success(function (data) {
                $log.info("available features length.." + data.length);
                listFeatures = data;
                d.resolve(listFeatures);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $log.error("Error while loading features: " + error);
                d.reject(error);
            });
    }
    return d.promise;
}
```

Here is a html:

```
    <ul class="items">

        <li data-ng-show="checkTabAvailable()" >
            <a href="#/tv">tv</a>
        </li>

        <li data-ng-show="checkTabAvailable()">
            <a href="#/Radio">Radio</a>
        </li>

        <li data-ng-show="checkTabAvailable()">
            <a href="#/extraF">extraF</a>
        </li>
```

As this is creating a many promise so getting a error:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
```

Is there any better way to load restEnd call once and then reuse in html side?

Comment: use `ng-init=checkTabAvailable()` in *ul* instead of each *li*

Comment: Avoid calling asynchronous functions with AngularJS Expressions in the HTML as they are called every digest cycle. The code as written doesn't make any sense, the `$http.get` will never be called. In addition, the `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and the `checkTabAvailable` function always returns `true`.